# Python TextWrapper, given n number lines

Tags: python

There is the python [Textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) to evenly fill out the words in a paragraph, given a width. However, I am looking to find a function in python in which I can give it a certain number of lines, and it will return the Text to fill that number of lines, as 'evenly' as possible.

Is there a module to do this?

Comment: Is that dependent on the fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say you have the text in a string `text`. You know the number of `lines` you want to fill. You could conceivably use `textwrap.wrap` (or `.fill`) on `text, (len(text) + lines - 1) / lines` to set your text evenly in the wanted number of lines.

Actually this can fail depending on the distribution of whitespace characters; in that case you could get more than `lines` lines of text. In that case, you could increase the width by some fixed amount until the text fits.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.4+, textwrap // wrap() has the kwarg "max_lines", where you can set the maximum number of lines you want displayed.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.max_lines